# destroying a Toplevel tk window in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to write code that would auto-close a Toplevel Tk window in Python.

I ended up getting it to work, but ran into a little problem along the way that I wasn't able to figure out.

The second two buttons work, but the first one doesn't and I don't understand why...

Any ideas?

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def doDestroy ():
    TL.destroy()

TL = Toplevel()
TL.b = Button (TL, text="lambda destroy", command=lambda: TL.destroy)
TL.b.pack()

TL.b2 = Button (TL, text="callback destroy", command=doDestroy)
TL.b2.pack()

de = lambda: TL.destroy()
TL.b3 = Button (TL, text="lambda that works", command=de)
TL.b3.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it returns a function and not its result.

You should put:

```
command=TL.destroy
```

or if you used lambda:

```
command=lambda: TL.destroy()
```

Comment: I understand that lambda returns a function, but isn't that the same as passing TL.destroy?   Both are references to functions, right?

Comment: no, lambda works exactly like def but it's anonymous, you have to put the same thing in the body. So in your try with lambda, command is not assigned a function, but a function returning a function (one indirection too much). Whereas TL.destroy is a function, so it's OK.